# How to use the same "back end" code with both a Zend web app and a Zend JSON-RPC server?

Tags: php, zend-framework, web-applications, mobile, json-rpc

I'm about to design a Zend web application which, in order to render its views, will use data which should also be retrievable through a JSON-RPC api, for mobile native apps. I was  wondering how to structure the project to keep these two parts independent. The web application is meant to be launched by going to the following URL:

http://www.domainname.com

Then, the iOS and Android client should be able to use the JSON-RPC api by sending post requests to

http://www.domainname.com/api/

Should the web application and the api be two separate zend applications or not? I'm skeptical about this because, as the data they will manage is substantially the same, the request handler classes and the controllers for the webapp will have a bunch of similar code to retrieve and manipulate the data to be returned.

Is there a good, clean and flexible way to use the same "back end" code for both the JSON-RPC server and the web app?

I would like to avoid code duplication but also make the api calls as fast as possible.

Thanks to anyone who will help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually achieve this quite easily.

When the controller handles it, use...

```
if ($this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest())
{
     // Code here
}
```

If you are saving data, the procedure can be the same. Usually, you would just use that to return a view or JSON. For example...

```
// Save the data here

if ($this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest())
{
     die(Zend_Json::encode(array('success' => true)));
}
else
{
     // View specific data here
}
```

I hope that helps and makes sense!

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. Since I'm not 100% comfortable with Zend yet, I was also asking for suggestions about the folder structure. What if I want to keep the web app and the api into a single project but reach them using two different urls? (please refer to the original question) All the tutorials I've seen suppose that the Zend application will be only reachable by index.php in the web_root folder.

Comment: Sorry, missed that part!

Perhaps you could make a plugin that would achieve this? Check out the Zend Framework MVC Controller dispatch process. You could probably write something that would check the URL and handle it accordingly.

Alternatively, you could make two seperate modules perhaps? Put all the code you want for the web app in a seperate folder called "api".
There are many approaches available. Check out the Zend Controller documentation, it may shed some light.